# How to get $x$ from $x(\ln(a/x))<c$?

Tags: inequality

Given an equality:
$$x(\ln(a/x))<c$$

Where $a,c,x\in \mathbb N$ and $ a>x$, I'd like to find something of the form $$x > f(a,c)$$

It doesn't have to be the exact domain of $x$ which satisfies the original inequality, but should provide a good approximation and (if possible) a simple explicit function $f$.

Any ideas as to how to get there?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Hoping that this could help you : the equation $$x \ln(\frac{a}{x})=c$$ has an explicit solution given by Lambert function $$x=-\frac{c}{W\left(-\frac{c}{a}\right)}$$  You must also notice that the function $$f(x)=x \ln(\frac{a}{x})-c$$ shows a maximum at $x_*=\frac{a}{e}$ and that $f(x_*)=\frac{a}{e}-c$ .